# Handle browser refresh button in Angular

Tags: angular, browser, angular-ui-router

I need to make a subject to false on browser refresh, back and front button in Angular. I handled back and front buttons by using onPopState event. Is there any event to handle refresh button too? I tried using window:beforeunload and window:onunload events but it didn't work.

**Note:** window:beforeunload and window:onunload events are working when application is started, I just need to trigger browser refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resolver in Angular to achieve this. From this, you will be able to handle the browser refresh of different routes separately. What happens here is resolver will execute some intermediate code, when a link has been clicked and before a component is loaded.

1. Create a service class implementing Resolve

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

   @Injectable()
   export class PathOneResolver implements Resolve<any> {
     constructor(
     ) { }

     resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
       // Make the subject false
       console.log('Browser Refresh on Path1');
     }
   }
   ```
2. Register the resolver service in module.ts file under providers

   ```
   import { PathOneResolver } from './services/worklist.resolver';

   @NgModule({
     providers: [ PathOneResolver ]
   })
   ```
3. Add the resolver in your route

   ```
   import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
   import { PathOneResolver } from './services/worklist.resolver';
   import { PathOneComponent} from '../main/components/pathone.component';
   import { BaseComponent } from '../main/components/base/base.component';

   export const approvalRoutes: Routes = [  
      { path: '', component: BaseComponent },  
      { path: 'pathone', component: PathOneComponent, resolve: 
        { pathone: PathOneResolver}}, 
   ];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the browser refresh with Angular,You need to look at the Angular Router. Specifically to the navigated property. This property is false when the router starts and after the first navigation it changes to true.

```
// in the constructor of you App Component
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      browserRefresh = !router.navigated;
    }
  });
}
```

You can set your desired property with in this function.